# Same Value of a variable is being used by multiple processes in PHP?

Tags: php

I have one program to calculate prizes of offers given by a shopping comp.
Prizes are being decided randomly.

I am running this program 1000000 times using a for loop in windows machine.
Its calculating correct win amount(as wins are random).

I ran the same program in Linux. In two different terminals, I am running the same program. Now the result of both programs is showing a huge win. Which is not looking possible according to the logic. Much bigger than the probability implemented.

I am surprised why it's happening! Is there any case like the same variable is being used in two separately running programs? Is there any role of static variables or any garbage value is being taken?

Please share your idea if any body is having any clue !

Comment: can you show that code `logic`

Comment: maybe your randomizer is being set to the same initial value.

Comment: I am just using the mt_rand() function in both cases. And in loop every time i am calling this function mt_rand() function.

Comment: Logic is covering multiple files along with HTML and CSS